# How to search files ended stars?

Tags: bash, find

I want to make script that searches,shows and delete for names ending in "*". My command:

```
echo rm `find -name "*[*]"`
```

Command works ,but I create file: something and something(ended star) Now after write command it, shows me : rm something(ended star) and similar file "something"
Why?

Comment: The output of `find -name "*[*]"` is `./something*`. So your command is like calling `rm ./something*`, and the bash will replace the `./something*` by a list of all files starting with `something`.

Comment: Thanks for advice but how can I save a star as the character on which the file name ends?

Comment: If you want to prevent the expansion of the glob, use double quotes `echo rm "$(find -name "*[*]")"`   Note that I've replaced backticks with $() for 2 reasons: 1) it's difficult to put backticks in a comment, and 2) backticks have have been superseded by `$()` for several decades.  Stop using them!

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan Hamcke states in comments, this is because the wildcard (`*`) from find's result ("something*") is passed as argument to `echo` and ends up being expanded again, resulting in the final output having both something and something*.

Do this instead:

```
find . -name "*[*]" -exec echo rm {} +
```

Output:

> rm ./something*

You can also achieve the same with the expression `"*\*"` in `find`.

Comment: This time, my output after entering your command is: rm rm ./something ./something*

Comment: That shouldn't be possible. What do you get if you just run find, without the `-exec` part ?

Comment: the same as before

Comment: Can you do a `ls` in your directory and paste the output or a screenshot in your question?

Comment: mariusz@mariusz-VirtualBox:~/folder$ ls
                                                                         about   something  'something*'
                                                            mariusz@mariusz-VirtualBox:~/folder$ echo rm                                                                             `find . -name "*[*]" -exec echo rm {} +`
rm rm ./something ./something*
mariusz@mariusz-VirtualBox:~/folder$

Comment: Ok, looks like you're trying to combine your command with mine. That wouldn't work. You should run just my command on its own (starting from `find` till the +).

Comment: How I can change this command to for? I try write this but it doesnt work:        for k in *[*];
do find . -name "$k" -exec echo rm {} +;
done;

Comment: @MarioFalcon I'll need more details on what you're trying to do. This command already finds all files with name ending with `*`. Why do you need this in a loop?

Comment: I need apply this command on other serwer. When I enter this command there is no message and no effects.

Comment: If by "other serwer" you mean that you connect over `ssh` to another server with the command as an argument to `ssh`, you need additional quoting because `ssh` basically causes another round of shell evaluation of the command to take place.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is that you do not quote the argument to `echo`.  Here is a trivial fix:

```
echo "rm $(find -name "*[*]")"
```

This is not entirely a minimal fix because I also replaced the obsolescent `` `backtick` `` syntax with the modern, recommended `$(command substitution)` syntax.

Without quotes, the string returned from the command substition gets evaluated by the shell for token splitting and wildcard expansion.  For details, see [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)